# Why do we need dependencies and devDependencies if babel knows how to build efficiently and remove excess from the project?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have read a lot of articles that say that the dependencies that are specified in the dependencies block are added to the build and the project will not start without them. I did so, transferred absolutely all the dependencies in the webpack to the devDependencies block and assembled the assemblies and launched the project. It starts off great, I come to the conclusion that there is absolutely no difference where to specify a dependency in the devDependencies or dependencies block. There is an assumption that `babel "runtime": "automatic"` itself knows how to control everything. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Here is an example of my project https://github.com/power23421/TestwebpackBabel where all dependencies are located in the devDependencies block and it works efficiently, you can move all dependencies to the dependencies block and it will also work efficiently. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: For client projects Babel creates a bundle which will include all the runtime code, regardless of where you put the dependencies.

For server projects, where the concept of bundling doesn't exist, usually only the modules in "dependencies" will be deployed, therefore you need to make sure all runtime dependences are listed under "dependencies".

Comment: it turns out that this will only affect the server where the build will be created? how can this be verified?

Comment: I do let's say the npm run build command works correctly

Comment: It also affects the installation of your dependencies. When you run "npm install" only the "dependencies" of each node module you depend on will be installed, so if you're creating a node module (let's say some library) you need to place your dependencies in the right place.

Comment: Regarding your question, not sure I got what you're asking.
When I say "server" projects I mean Node.js.

Comment: I mean, I installed the packages all in the wrong partition devDependencies. this shouldn't work since some of the packages should be in the section Dependencies. But it works somehow

Comment: When you run "npm install", it installs both the "dependencies" and the "devDependencies" of your project.  

If you need to deploy your Node.js project to a production server or publish a library to NPM you need to make sure all runtime dependencies are under "dependencies", because that's what will be deployed/published alongside your source-code.

Comment: I understand so that when I make a launch on the server, the dependencies that are in devDependencies will not be installed on the server?

Comment: Yes.

"devDependencies" will be installed during the build on whatever CI tool you're using, but they are usually omitted when deploying the project to a production server because they are not required in runtime.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Of course, it's interesting to see how the server collects everything with a small number of modules))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name says, `dev dependencies` are tools that you need for development. for example, when you work with `webpack`, you need a lot of packages for webpack, "webpack" itself, maybe "webpack-dev-server" or other plugins. And also for babel set up, you need alot of other packages. All of those are needed to create the final `bundle`. After creating a bundle you do not need these packages, so when you deploy your app, your server does not need to install those and maintain those. Your app in production will run without those.

Packages that you need for testing are also dev dependencies. you test the app in the dev environment, not in a production environment.

On the other hand, if you have a database connection package, this is the dependency that your project needs when you deploy the app. Otherwise, your clients will not be able to connect database. In fact if you install a dependency as dev-dependency by mistake, when you deploy the app your app will give errors. `Dependencies` are essential packages that your app need in `production`.